# read a graph by vertices not as an edge list in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, graph, igraph

**To explain:** I have an undirected graph stored in a text file as edges where each line consist of two values represent an edge, like:

```
5 10
1000 2
212 420
  .
  . 
  .
```

Normally when reading a graph in R from a file (using **igraph**), it will be read as edges so to call the edges of the graph "g" we write `E(g)` and to call the vertices of "g" we write `V(g)` and to call both vertices of a certain edge **(i.e to call a certain edge (edge i))** we write `E(g)[i]`.

**My question:** Is there a similar way to call one vertex only inside an edge not to call both of them.

For example, if I need the second vertex in the third edge then what I need to type?
Also from the beginning, is there something on igraph to read the graph as vertices and not as edges? like to read the graph as a table with two columns such that each edge to be read as X[i][1], X[i][2].

I need this because I want to do a loop among all vertices and to choose them separately from the edge and I think it is possible if each vertex was labeled like an element in a table.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a two column table with vertices, you could use `graph_from_data_frame` to convert it into graph. To get nodes on particular edge, you can use `ends`.

```
#DATA
set.seed(2)
m = cbind(FROM = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, TRUE), TO = sample(LETTERS[6:10], 10, TRUE))

#Convert to graph
g = graph_from_data_frame(m, directed = FALSE)
#plot(g)

#Second vertex on third edge
ends(graph = g, es = 3)[2]
#[1] "I"
```

Comment: thanks for you cooperation. But when writing the graph to an outfile, is it possible to write it as vertices not as an edge list?

Comment: @user8003788, do you want `get.edgelist(g)`?