# The function "ends" is not exist although igraph was installed

Tags: r, igraph, r-package

I am unable to continue writing the code down below because of the `ends(graph, es, names = TRUE)` function ([the description](http://igraph.org/r/doc/ends.html)).

I installed `igraph` library and I verified from everything but the ends function keep giving me an error.

```
> library(igraph)
> setwd("Desktop")
> file <- "distance"
> con <- file(description=file, open="r")
> line <- read.table(con)
> data<-as.data.frame(line) 
> df <- graph.data.frame(d = data, directed = FALSE) #to convert data to a graph object
> edge<-sample(E(df),1)  # sample an edge randomly
> edge
  Edge sequence:
    e             
  e [16567] 5578 -- 6774
> ends(graph = g, es = 'e')[2]  #get the second vertex for edge e
Error in ends(graph = g, es = "e") : could not find function "ends"
```

The file "distance" contain the data which it is a set of edges ordered in two columns, each row is an edge and each value in the column represent a vertex as:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

so `1 2` is an edge between the vertices 1 & 2.

I want this function to get the incident vertices of a randomly selected edge, I searched the interent and R libraries but I a can't find a similar function or something to do the same which allow me to select a certain vertex from an edge, here is a similar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426620/read-a-graph-by-vertices-not-as-an-edge-list-in-r) but the proposed solution is to use `ends()`.

Could you kindly tell me why I am unable to use this function or to propose another function for the same purpose.
Many thanks in advance

**EDIT**

It seems that the problem is the version of igraph !! the `ends(graph,..)` is not defined in this version.

My question now,
Because it is impossible to upgrade the igraph version, is there other functions to select a certain vertex from an edge? 
Thanks

Comment: What version is your `igraph`? Maybe share `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Gregor  it is igraph_0.7.1, so I think this the reason!! this function is not defined. Is there other similar functions ? or any function to select a certain vertex from an edge?

Comment: How about you just update your package? That version is almost 4 years old. The major update in 2015 introduced `ends`, and there was a nice update in 2017 too. Otherwise you could copy the `ends` code from the current version and hope it works, but there's no guarantee that it will.

Comment: @Gregor I tried to update it previously but I faced a lot of problems. SO now I am looking for another function to do the same job as ends(graph)

Comment: I would suggest editing your question so that the title and the first few lines reflect the problem rather than just the last two lines. I don't think it will get much interest as it is now. Also, if you took my advice in the previous comment about copying the `ends` function, mention that and tell how it went. (Of course, if it works you can just close the question.)

Comment: @Gregor thanks for your note. In fact its too hard to update (igraph) in my case, it is too complicated situation. Also, I failed to use the ends function but I achieved my goal in another way using get.edgelist(graph)...Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I understand you can't update `igraph`. As I said above, *you could copy the `ends` code from the current version and hope it works*. But I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help who would face the same problems..

my aim was to read the edges by vertices so that I can call any vertex in an edge, so I transformed the data from `igraph` object to `edgelist` by adding the following lines

```
edges<-get.edgelist(df)
v1<-edges[edge,1]
v2<-edges[edge,2]
edge
Edge sequence:
              e             
e [8839] 1149 -- 1425
v1
[1] "1425"
v2
[1] "1149"
```

It is not a great solution but it solved my problem so maybe it could help other beginners like me

Comment: Or you could use the idea of your solution to make a function to replace `ends` like this `ENDS = function(g, v) { get.edgelist(g)[v,] }`